# How to get a div containing and image element to have the same height as the image

Tags: css

I have this html code:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/319x300" alt="">
<div>
```

and this css:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div{
    background: red;
    width: 319px;
    height: auto;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

However the background color of the `div` shows at the bottom. Is there a way make the container be the same height as the image? On the site I am working on, I have Erics Reset styles and also there is no `padding` or `margin` that conflicts with this. This is the sample code http://jsfiddle.net/ESmZW/1/
Thanks

Comment: You have to use javascript

Comment: Try setting "display: block" on the image and see if that does the trick for you.

Comment: Another option is to float the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way is to add the `vertical-align:top` property to the image

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ESmZW/4/)**

You could also float the image left and add the overflow:auto rule to the div like in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ESmZW/7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Set "display:block" on the image.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute/relative positionning:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div{
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    width: 319px;
    height: auto;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@aurel If all you wanted was to have the div be the size of your image, why not set it's height and width to the size of your image? Your HTML also doesn't close your div. See my modifications on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ESmZW/12/).

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/319x300" width="319" height="300" alt="">
</div>

body {
    margin:0;
}


div {
    background: red;
    width: 319px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: The images would be different sizes.